# Flutter input files override deprecated API after Kotlin version upgrade to fix a mismatch for location package

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I had this error after adding `location`: (truncated similar errors)

```
C:\Users\Abrikosas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-5.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt:
(283, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin.
The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
```

After changing kotlin to: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'`  I am no longer getting a fatal error and the app builds. However, I am now getting a red colored text `Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.` App seems to work fine for now, but I know I should not build with this note/warning present. I tried a few other versions in between versions of 1.7.21 and 1.9.10, but they all seem to throw the note warning. How can I solve this?

Flutter version: `3.7.12` (don't want to go to Dart 3 for now).
location version: `5.0.3`
Running on a real Galaxy S10 via USB.

I do `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` before each run when debugging this. `flutter doctor` has all checkmarks.